# trying to create one row with a few columns in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create grid in bootstrap but no matter how I defined the column - each column  goes down to a new row - instead of creating one long row.

That the code I tried (its from the w3schools tutorial):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"      
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks fine to me, and works well enough. http://www.bootply.com/HAOYih4S2V

Comment: What browser are you viewing this in that's causing the rows to become their own individual rows instead of 4 columns in the same row?

Answer (score 0):

The only likely reason your columns are becoming their own rows is because the window/viewport/area you're using them in is smaller than 768 pixels wide.

Easiest way to maintain your column layout from the largest screen size to even the smallest is to use the `col-xs-*` classes instead of the sm, md or lg versions.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
     <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-xs-4</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-xs-4</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-xs-4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1npgqfmk/)**

If you drag the right divider bar of the results area to make it wider or narrower, you'll see that the columns always remain on the same row and never wrap to the next one. If you need some kind of wrapping, then you'll need to set up how they wrap by adding the correct grid classes to each row based on how you want them to wrap at certain window/viewport widths.